# how to apply discount

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a ticket purchase system to get better in my javascript. I need help with some of my code. I can get the total of everything I want, but I am unable to get my discount function to work.

The total is calculated as (Show price * number of tickets) + (price of the delivery method)

when: the number of tickets > 6 the discount should be 10 per cent of the total. 
when: the number of tickets > 10 the discount should be 15 per cent of the total.

the discount should be displayed separately to the total.

Dont mind some of the code  that are comments  as i used that as refrences.

This is the code:

java script:

```
//constants
const name = document.getElementById("fname");
const noofaddress = document.getElementById("noofaddress");
const shows = document.getElementById("shows");
const delivery = document.getElementById("delivery");
const displaytotal = document.getElementById("displaytotal");
const seatprice = document.getElementById("seatprice");
const order = document.getElementById("book");
const showselect = document.querySelector("#shows");

//event listeners
//order.addEventListener("click", gettotal);
//showselect.addEventListener("change", getshowprice);

//amount
var showprices = new Array();
showprices["79"]=79;
showprices["85"]=85;
showprices["67"]=67;
showprices["83"]=83;

function getshowprice() {
const display = document.getElementById("display");

    var showprice = 0;
    var form = document.forms["bookform"];
    var selectedshow = form.elements["shows"]

    showprice = showprices[selectedshow.value];
    return showprice;
}

//event listeners
//order.addEventListener("click", gettotal);
//showselect.addEventListener("change", getshowprice);

//functions

//function calculateshowcost() {
    //showcost = Number(this.value);
    //document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = (`£${bookform.shows[bookform.shows.selectedIndex].value}`);
//}

//delivery funtion
//function getDeliveryValue() {
   // document.getElementById('displaydelivery').innerHTML = (`£${bookform.delivery[bookform.delivery.selectedIndex].value}`);
//}

var deliveryprices = new Array();
deliveryprices["0"]=0;
deliveryprices["1.50"]=1.50;
deliveryprices["3.99"]=3.99;

function getdeliveryprice() {
const displaydelivery = document.getElementById("displaydelivery");
    var deliveryprice = 0;
    var form = document.forms["bookform"];
    var selecteddelivery = form.elements["delivery"]

    deliveryprice = deliveryprices[selecteddelivery.value];
    return deliveryprice;
}


function gettotal() {
const displaytotal = document.getElementById("displaytotal");
const seats = document.getElementById("seats");
const noofseats = document.querySelector("#seats");
    var showtotal = getshowprice()
    var showdeliverytotal = getdeliveryprice()
    var seatstotal = noofseats.value;
    displaytotal.innerText = (`Total: £${(showtotal * seatstotal) + (showdeliverytotal)}`);
}



function getdiscount(products, showtotal, seatstotal) {

const discount = document.getElementById('discount');
  var x = 6

if (seatstotal > x) {



(seatstotal > 10) 
      DiscountPrice = showtotal - (showtotal * .10)


}
else if 
   {
     DiscountPrice = showtotal - (showtotal * .10)
}
return showtotal > y;


  discount.innerText =  (`discount: £${(DiscountPrice)}`);



// total 
//function totalprice(event) {
    //event.preventDefault()
    //showprice = Number(showselect.value);
    //totalnumberoftickets = Number(noofseats.value);
    //totalcost = (showprice * totalnumberoftickets) + deliverycost;
    //displaytotal.innerText = totalTickets;
    //totalPriceResult.innerText = totalPrice;
    //console.log("thank you for your order")
//}
```

html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="theatre tickets page for assignment">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theatretickets.css">
    <title>Theatre Tickets</title>
</head>

<body class="background">
<script src="theatretickets.js"></script>
    <img class="logoimage" src="" alt="logo">
    <h1 class="title">Theatre Tickets</h1>

<!--navigation -->
    <nav>
        <ul class="a">
            <li class="hp"><a href="fruitmachine.html">Fruit Machine</a></li>
            <li class="hp"><a href="theatretickets.html">Theatre Tickets</a></li>
        </ul><br><br>
    </nav>

<!--forms-->

<!--name-->
    <form name="bookform" id="bookform" class="fullform" method="post">
        <h2>Name</h2>
        <label for="fname">Full Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required=""><br>

 <!--address-->
        <h2>Address</h2>
        <label for="noofaddress">Full Address</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="noofaddress" name="noofaddress" required=""><br>

<!--shows-->
        <h2>Currently Available Shows</h2>
        <select name="shows" id="shows" onchange="getshowprice()">
            <option value="79" selected class="Phantom" id="Phantom">Phantom Of The Opera</option>
            <option value="85" class="hamilton" id="hamilton">Hamilton</option>
            <option value="67" class="lionking" id="lionking">Lion King</option>
            <option value="83" class="misssaigon" id="misssaigon">Miss Saigon</option>
        </select><br>
        <label id="display"></label>

<!--delivery-->
        <h2>Method Of Delivery</h2>
        <select id="delivery" name="delivery" onchange="getdeliveryprice()">
            <option id="eticket" value="0" selected>E-Ticket</option>
            <option id="boxoffice" value="1.50">Collect from Box Office</option>
            <option id="posted" value="3.99">Posted</option>
        </select><br>


<!--display the delivery cost label-->
        <label id="displaydelivery"></label>

<!--seats-->
        <h2>Number Of Seats</h2>
        <input type="number" id="seats" name="seats" min="1" required=""
        placeholder="Number of Seats"><br>

        <label id="seatprice"></label><br><br>

<!--book button-->
        <button type="button" name="book" id="book" onclick="gettotal()">Book</button><br><br>
        <div id= "displaytotal"></div>
        <div id="discount"></div>
        <div id="finalcost"></div>
    </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: You're missing a `{` in your else if clause of your discount conditional checks.  Other than that... what is your question?  Are you not getting the result you expect?  Or ?  Also, you should check if the seats are greater than 10 first.  Then if greater than 6.  Because if seats is 11, it will meet your check if it's greater than 6, and never hit the greater than 10 condition.

Comment: I would suggest learning how to separate your view problems from your logic problems first. Here is something you can play around with to get the calculations just right: https://jsfiddle.net/6dozgjLt/12/, then as a separate task, apply these calculations into your view. Post back if you get stuck.

Comment: Hi Devin, I really appreciate the feedback. I have made the recommended changes but I am still not able to get the discount to show up.

Answer (score 0):

When no. of ticket is greater than 10, you are still applying 10%, so replace it with 15%, and I think you should first check condition for 10 and then condition for 6 in your if-else, see the new edited code. I don't know what is y here so can't comment on that.

```
//constants
const name = document.getElementById("fname");
const noofaddress = document.getElementById("noofaddress");
const shows = document.getElementById("shows");
const delivery = document.getElementById("delivery");
const displaytotal = document.getElementById("displaytotal");
const seatprice = document.getElementById("seatprice");
const order = document.getElementById("book");
const showselect = document.querySelector("#shows");

//event listeners
//order.addEventListener("click", gettotal);
//showselect.addEventListener("change", getshowprice);

//amount
var showprices = new Array();
showprices["79"]=79;
showprices["85"]=85;
showprices["67"]=67;
showprices["83"]=83;

function getshowprice() {
const display = document.getElementById("display");

    var showprice = 0;
    var form = document.forms["bookform"];
    var selectedshow = form.elements["shows"]

    showprice = showprices[selectedshow.value];
    return showprice;
}

//event listeners
//order.addEventListener("click", gettotal);
//showselect.addEventListener("change", getshowprice);

//functions

//function calculateshowcost() {
    //showcost = Number(this.value);
    //document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = (`£${bookform.shows[bookform.shows.selectedIndex].value}`);
//}

//delivery funtion
//function getDeliveryValue() {
   // document.getElementById('displaydelivery').innerHTML = (`£${bookform.delivery[bookform.delivery.selectedIndex].value}`);
//}

var deliveryprices = new Array();
deliveryprices["0"]=0;
deliveryprices["1.50"]=1.50;
deliveryprices["3.99"]=3.99;

function getdeliveryprice() {
const displaydelivery = document.getElementById("displaydelivery");
    var deliveryprice = 0;
    var form = document.forms["bookform"];
    var selecteddelivery = form.elements["delivery"]

    deliveryprice = deliveryprices[selecteddelivery.value];
    return deliveryprice;
}


function gettotal() {
const displaytotal = document.getElementById("displaytotal");
const seats = document.getElementById("seats");
const noofseats = document.querySelector("#seats");
    var showtotal = getshowprice()
    var showdeliverytotal = getdeliveryprice()
    var seatstotal = noofseats.value;
    displaytotal.innerText = (`Total: £${(showtotal * seatstotal) + (showdeliverytotal)}`);
}



function getdiscount(products, showtotal, seatstotal) {

const discount = document.getElementById('discount');
var x = 10;
var DiscountPrice = 0;

if (seatstotal > x) {
  DiscountPrice = showtotal - (showtotal * .15)
}
else if 

     (seatstotal > 6) 
      DiscountPrice = showtotal - (showtotal * .10)
}
return showtotal > y;


  discount.innerText =  (`discount: £${(DiscountPrice)}`);



// total 
//function totalprice(event) {
    //event.preventDefault()
    //showprice = Number(showselect.value);
    //totalnumberoftickets = Number(noofseats.value);
    //totalcost = (showprice * totalnumberoftickets) + deliverycost;
    //displaytotal.innerText = totalTickets;
    //totalPriceResult.innerText = totalPrice;
    //console.log("thank you for your order")
//}
```

Comment: Hello, I am very thankful for your answer but I am still not able to display the discount. As for the variable y, it is just miscellaneous and I have removed it.

Comment: @AdilOmarji, have you declared DiscountPrice variable before using it, I guess that may be causing the problem, assuming you are doing right everywhere else. you can use inspect element feature of browser to see the different type of error that may be happening with your javascript code. updated the above code.